# How can i show the recently added bookmarked posts on the top of list using php or other tools?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, list

I am working on a website that gives users an option to bookmark or favorite any post to read it later on. If anyone favorites a post then it is added to that list.

The list is showing the more recent posts (according to the post's published date) on the top but I want the list to show in order that the posts were favorited. This is because when a user favorites any old post then they have to struggle through a bundle of their favorited posts to get to the recently bookmarked/favorited post

```
<?php 
  $favorites = get_user_favorites();
  $x = 1;
?>
<?php   
  if ($favorites) : $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
  $favorites_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'post__in' => $favorites,
    'paged' => $paged 
  ));

  echo "<ol class='favorite-list-ol'>";
?>
<?php
  if ($favorites_query->have_posts()) : while ( $favorites_query->have_posts() ) : $favorites_query->the_post();
?>

<li class="favorite-list-li">
  <?php echo get_the_title($favorite); ?> 
</li>

<?php
  endwhile;
  $x++;
  echo "</ol>"; 
?>
```

Comment: I recommend you to create a custom field to store the date the post was favorited (or added) by the user. Then, you can just get the data based on this date (and not the date of publish) using [WP_Meta_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) or better yet `meta_query` argument in [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters). Note that there is a DATETIME field type.

Comment: Yup i liked your idea but i am still learning coding and cant create custom field yet. can you help me out to create a meta_query please..

Comment: From where `get_user_favorites()` comes from? Is it a plugin?

Comment: yes it is plugin that shows star icon on the Post upon clicking it the post adds on to the Favorite list.

Comment: What is the plugin you're using? I guess it could already have this feature in place.